# navigation between activities using up button

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to android development. I have three activities
1. Main Activity
2. Category Activity
3. Subcategory Activity

I want navigation like
1. from main activity to category (intent activity)
2. from main activity to Subcategory (intent activity )
3. from Subcategory to category (intent activity )
4. from category to main activity (using up button via parent child relation in manifest)
5. from subcategory to main activity (using up button via parent child relation in manifest)
but the problem is
**6. category to subcategory.(back navigation using up button overriding up button functionality)**
**7.. subcategory to subcategory : I called subcategory from subcategory(recurse if subcategory has more subcategory) I can change design of subcategory if necessary.**

need your valuable suggestion 
here are images and will post code if necessary.

MAIN ACTIVITY
![Main activity][1]

SUBCATEGORY ACTIVITY
![SubActivity][2]

ITERATED SUB CATEGORY![category][4]

CATEGORY ACTIVITY![subcategory iterated][3]

Comment: Please have a look of my answer.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique I guess, he already tried what you answered, but have some other trouble. So, just needed to make it sure.

Comment: Yes i have done that

Comment: My sub category activity calls itself  if their some more multilevel category. Is their  any good solution like adding fragment in subcategory activity and refreshing it rather than calling sub category again and again. Will this give me proper navigation using up button

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) class to switch between activities.

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I have some design issue. I have created a subcategory activity that iterate itself. As you can see it contain a expandable list view and if a child has a subcategory then it load subcategory activity otherwise call category activity.

Comment: Is their any way we can have up navigation inside subcategory. I mean to that what if we add fragment rather than calling subactivity again and again.

Answer (score 1):

An Intent is a messaging object you can use to request an action from another app component. Although intents facilitate communication between components in several ways, there are three fundamental use-cases

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondScreen.class);
StartActivity(i);
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/